# Run javascript on a specific execution context

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I am trying to write a javascript that renames the text of a button on a website.

```
setInterval(function() {
        
        let Bestellbutton2 = document.getElementsByClassName("_7tbHf _3LH_L");
       
        Bestellbutton2[0].innerHTML = "Anfrage absenden";}, 500);
```

The problem I'm having seems to be the execution context. This code only works if I inspect the element first, or if I manually change the execution context from above to the selected one (checkout).

[image: 1]

How can I solve this problem?

This code works only if i inspect element first, or if manually change execution context form top to the one selected (chekcout).

Comment: You want it to be DevTools Snippets instead of content scripts?

Comment: Hi, I would like my code as contet script not as DevTools Snippets in Chrome.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto Hi, would you have an idea how i could solve my problem?